# How show or appears the TitleBar? (I'd set NoTitleBar in Manifest.xml)

Tags: android, manifest, titlebar

I'm looking for to set the default titlebar in one layout into my app. But I'd set the Theme of the app to NoTitleBar.

How can I add by code to set/appear the titlebar?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the theme for each activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name="Activity1"  android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
<activity android:name="Activity"  android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/SOMETHING_ELSE"/>
```

Comment: @JCDelValle, then will you accept this as the answer, also it will raise your rep and make people more likely to help you if you accept answers on your previous questions as well

Answer (score 0):

You can override a theme set on `<application>`, by defining theme on `<activity>`.